# Windows 10 freezing randomly

Tags: windows-10, freeze

Something has recently been happening to my computer where I'll be using it and it will just freeze. The audio cuts out, the screen is frozen, I can't use the mouse and the caps lock key doesn't change the light on my keyboard. I've only seen it happen while I'm playing a game, not in normal use. For example, I play Rocket League and after about half an hour my PC will freeze and I'll have to hold the power button down until it turns off. Since it was happening during periods of high stress I figured it must be to do with heat issues, so I ramped up my fan settings on MSI Afterburner. The GPU was sat around 61°C for the whole time, and I was able to play for much longer (5 or so hours), but it eventually happened again. Another suggestion I found on the internet was to adjust a setting under PCIe power settings, but I had already switched this off. I also tried updating my graphics drivers and looking in device manager for driver updates, but had no luck here either. Can I fix this?

Specs:

AMD FX-6300 six-core processor

Radeon R7 260X

Windows 10

I use Ethernet for internet and have a mouse, keyboard, headphones and an xbox controller plugged into the USB ports.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the computer used to freeze and upon checking the Task Manager disk usage was at 100% by a system process: https://redd.it/3h4wjg

Comment: Welcome to Super User.  You're suggesting to use Task Manager to look for anything that is hogging the system?  If something is found, what's the next step?  The link is to a forum thread that goes on forever.  Is there something specific there, or is that intended just as related reading that could contain something useful?  Thanks.